# Determining the Convergence of Improper Integral with Given Limit

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function defined for $x \geq 0$ such that $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \geq 0$. Additionally, suppose that

$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) =a$$

where $a$ is a finite constant.

Is this information sufficient to prove that the improper integral

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) \, dx
\
$$

diverges, i.e.,

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) \, dx = +\infty ?
$$

Comment: If $a$ is positive or negative then if will diverge to positive or negative infinity respectively. If $a = 0$ then we can't say.

Comment: Can you provide a proof ?

Comment: There exists some $K>0$ such that $f(x) > a/2$ for all $x > K$. Do the integral from $0$ to $K$ and then $K$ to infinity.

Comment: Why is f(x) > a/2 ? Also , thank you for your asnwer.

Comment: I just took $a/2$. You can take any other number between $0$ and $a$ and apply definition of limit. The $K$ will be different but it will be finite.